# Wrap API Promise Function With Callback in Observer

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

### Background

I am using an API that uses success and failure callbacks on each function. I have expanded on a wrapper layer over it that uses Promises to account for the success and failure callbacks but there are functions that take an additional callback as their parameter, such as the following:

**Low Level JS API**

```
function addProgressListener(successCallback, failureCallback, progressCallback);
```

**TypeScript Wrapper**

```
function addProgressListenerAsync(progressCallback): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    addProgressListener(
      () => resolve(true),
      (err) => reject(err),
      progressCallback);
  });
}
```

At a higher level I am using this in an async/await style but since the progressCallback will be return multiple values that I would like to attach to a ProgressBar component, I want to wrap it in an Observable.

### Question

How do I wrap just the progressCallback portion in an Observable? I cannot wrap the entire call to addProgressListener because it is being used in an async/await fashion like so:

```
async function process(): Promise<any> {
  try {

    await addProgressListener((value) => {
       // Value = percentage complete
       // How do I get this value into an Observable that my component can bind to?
    }

    // ... do actual processing stuff
  }
  catch(err) {
  }
```

I was thinking that I could create the Observable prior to calling the function and somehow add the "observer.next(value)" call inside the callback similar to the answer I received on this question [Wrap API Call in Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990606/wrap-an-api-function-in-an-rxjs-observable) but looking through the RxJS documentation I don't see a way to add the .next() callback to already created instance of an Observable, only inside the Observable.create's callback (which would require I wrap the call to addProgressListenerAsync...).

I would also accept any suggestions as to an alternate way to write wrapper to accomplish this, although the Promise style work has already been done so it may not be practical to rewrite the whole thing to use Observables.

Comment: Just keep what you have. It seems clear and simple enough. Unless the use will have multiple, _correlated_ event sources you will not be improving the API. The reason is that you won't need the combinators. Also remember that observable marries you to even more callbacks.

Comment: You can use a subject instead

Comment: @FanCheung a subject is an observable, just an incredibly powerful and overused one that also happens to be an observer. Developers of RX in both .NET and JavaScript have written at length how about how reaching for subjects is an antipattern.

Comment: then why they create subject, also all variety of subjects. Personally I prefer code simplicity, you can always use asobservable to seal the subject methods.

Comment: After doing more research I did come across Subjects and tried using them by creating the subject and then inside the callback, calling the subject.next(). It is interesting to hear that they are considered an anti-pattern though...
Also, the unstated reason for needing the Observable was that the component I had hooked up to listen to the value being updated in the callback wasn't updating. After switching to a Subject, it still did not update so the issue may lay elsewhere.